# How to redefine addEventListener to be attachEvent in older versions of IE

Tags: javascript

I have a plugin with many lines like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

this.drop.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
```

I want to have a bit of javascript at the top which redefines addEventListener so it actually uses attachEvent in older browsers (I can use the navigator object). I don't want to have to do if statements for every line of code like above.

Comment: Have you considered using a micro library? http://microjs.com/#event

Answer (score 0):

```
var addEvent = function (ele, event, func) {
    if (ele.addEventListener) {
        ele.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    } else if (ele.attachEvent) {
        ele.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
    } else {
        ele['on' + event] = func;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add this event yourself.

This is the simplest implementation I can think of:

```
if (!Element.addEventListener)
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(event,handler, placeholder) {
    this.attachEvent('on'+event,handler);
}
```

After running this in the beginning of the page, you should be able to use `addEventListener` on your elements. I wrote **should** because you'll need more functions like this in order to use the same code on all browsers. Your best option is to use an existing code (like in polyfill) that will handle all of this.